# Limit Windows 8 "Automatic Maintenance" to single CPU core?

Tags: windows-8, multi-core

Windows 8's Automatic Maintenance has the nasty trait of hijacking my machine when I leave it idle. It becomes completely unresponsive after a while. In lieu of a proper solution by Microsoft, I thought maybe it's possible to limit the number of CPU cores used by Automatic Maintenance, so I can still use my machine when it happens. (To access Task Manager and kill the damned Maintenance, for example.)

Comment: Using the task manager you can change the CPU assignment of a process from any core to one specific core.

Comment: Yes but there's a problem with that. Automatic Maintenance is not a single process. It is a range of Windows processes, and worse, it differs which ones on a case-by-case basis.